# Need help creating a single formula to find the probability of successfully rolling multiple 6-sided dice with conditions.

Tags: probability, statistics

Example question: If you roll 7 dice, what is the probability of successfully rolling a 5 **or higher**, **at least** 4 times?
Let a=7 b=5 c=4.
My goal is to plug a,b,c into a long formula and have the probability of success for the example above.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of a Bernoulli trial, and the application of the binomial theorem to these situations?

Comment: When you say 4 times, do you mean, in a row?

Comment: The probability of $5$ or higher in a single roll is $2/6$. So the probability it happens $4$ times in $7$ rolls is $\binom{7}{4}(2/6)^4(4/6)^3$. Please see Binomial Distribution on Wikipedia or elsewhere. Similarly the probability it happens $5$ times in $7$ rolls is $\binom{7}{5}(2/6)^5(4/6)^2$.  Write down similar expressions for it happens $6$ times, for it happens $7$ times, and add up.

Answer (score 0):

**Simulation.** A simulation of a million 7-dice experiments in R is as follows. (At the end, the vector `big` contains the number of 5'5 or 6's seen on the seven dice rolled in each experiment.)

```
 m = 10^6;  n = 7;  big = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   roll = sample(1:6, n, rep=T)
   big[i] = sum(roll >= 5)  }
 mean(big >= 4)   # proportion of expts with at least four 5's or 6's
 ## 0.173095      # Approx. answer
```

The following relative frequency histogram summarizes the one million results. (There were 463 results out of a million with seven `big` results, but they are relatively too few to show on this scale.)

[image]

**Exact formula.** Now for a formula that gives the exact answer, based on the
Comment by @AndreNicholas.  Let $f(i, 7, 2/6) = {7 \choose i} (2/6)^i(4/6)^{7-i}$, for $i = 0, 1, \dots, 7,$ be the PDF
(or PMF, depending on text) of the Binomial distribution
based on $n = 7$ trials with success probability $p = 2/6$
on each trial. Also let $F(x, 7, 2/6) = \sum_{i=0}^x f(i, 7, 2/6)$
be the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of this binomial
distribution. You should match my notation with the notation
in your text.

In R, the function `dbinom` denotes the PDF and `pbinom` denotes the CDF.
Thus, your answer, $\sum_{i=4}^7 f(i, 7, 2/6) = 1 - F(3, 7, 2/6) = 0.1732968$
can be computed in R in two ways:

```
 i = 4:7; sum(dbinom(i, 7, 2/6)) 
 ## 0.1732968  # exact answer summing PDF terms
 1 - pbinom(3, 7, 2/6)
 ## 0.1732968  # exact answer using CDF
```

Notice that the simulation was accurate to three places.

The figure below shows a bargraph of the PDF of $Binom(7, 2/6),$
with the four probabilities that add to your answer (including the tiny probability at 7) highlighted as thick
blue bars.

[image]